# How show "repost" like retweets in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a project where I have posts that can be reposted to the pure style of twitter (retweets). The posts are saved in a table "posts" (id, userid, title, content, date) and the reposts are saved in another table "reposts" (postid, userid, date). I need to show posts and reposts of a user arranged chronologically and in a descending order.

So far what I have been able to do is show both tables but the reposts are shown ordered with the creation date of the post, not with the date of the repost. If I repost a post from 2 years ago, I want the post to be shown now (reposts date), and not ordered with the posts from 2 years ago (posts date).

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT p.* FROM post AS p WHERE userid='$id' UNION SELECT p.* FROM post AS p WHERE p.id IN (SELECT postid FROM repost WHERE userid='$id')) a ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: Why did you remove the sql tag but kept the php tag? I don't see any PHP (OK, `$id` is there, but that's less than minor) but plenty of SQL.

Comment: I have already edited it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join `reposts` and `posts` and pick the columns you want from each table.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT p1.postid,
                    p1.userid,
                    p1.title,
                    p1.content,
                    p1.date
                    FROM posts p1
                    WHERE p1.userid = ?
             UNION ALL
             SELECT r1.postid,
                    r1.userid,
                    p2.title,
                    p2.content,
                    r1.date
                    FROM reposts r1
                         INNER JOIN posts p2
                                    ON p2.postid = r1.postid
                    WHERE r1.userid = ?) x
       ORDER BY x.date DESC;
```

Comment: Happy someone else answered.  That query made me dizzy.  @LOSDEV, I would suggest in the future to not get hung up on doing everything you are trying to do in one query.  Create temp tables if you have to.  Get to your end result by stepping through and then try to build your final query based on those steps.

Comment: Thank you very much sticky bit, I was going crazy. I need to learn a lot more about mysql. And thanks for the tip Bleach! ^^